# Как сделать так, чтобы бот считывал повторение никнеймов?

Tags: discord

хочу сделать так, чтобы бот считывал повторение никнеймов (для дискорд бота), но как мне это сделать? (Застрял на if)

```
    @bot.event()
async def ban():
    while True:
        with open('argue.txt.txt', 'r') as b:
            b.read()
            if
```

Comment: вы хотите сканировать ники всех участников на предмет выявления дублирующихся? судя по названию функции вы планируете выдавать бан. А банить вы планируете оба ника или какой то один?

Comment: нет, не бан, а оповещение в канал, и надо, чтобы через повторение 3-х раз никнейма, он делал оповещение